# is this generic/non-generic combo repository example mockable?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, repository-pattern

I read that one of the main reasons for using the unit of work/repository pattern is so that your data access layer can be mocked during unit testing. If that is true then making a repository like this (seen on various blogs on the subject) seems to me like it would make things more complicated than they need to be when it comes to mocking. How would you mock the methods of *GenericRepository* given that you only have *ICustomerRepository* to work with in the mocking framework?

```
public class CustomerRepository : GenericRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(ObjectContext context) : base(context) { }

    public IList<Customer> NewlySubscribed()
    {
        var lastMonth = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);

        return GetQuery().Where(c => c.Inserted >= lastMonth)
        .ToList();
    }

    public Customer FindByName(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        return GetQuery().Where(c => c.Firstname == firstname && c.Lastname == lastname).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, maybe i should have read a book (but they are so time consuming) about object oriented programming before i asked this question, ICustomerRepository inherits from IGenericRepository and everything unit tests just fine.